# Discover Powershell output property names

Tags: powershell

I am running some Powershell code which gets the latest TFS branch label, something like this

```
tf labels /owner:LBLD_V3_R10* | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Now is there a way I can see which properties are in that returned object?

I know about Get-Member but it seems to be treating the returned PS Object as a string.

Comment: You're getting the last item in a collection of strings. Would you not expect it to be a string?

Comment: Right but is there a way to split up the object into properties? The returned labels include more information than is necessary and I'd rather not mess about with substring, indexof, etc

Comment: Is the `tf` command an executable or a cmdlet? If it's just a normal command-line application, then all it will be putting on the pipeline is a string, which powershell is conveniently breaking into an array of strings for you. `Select-Object` is selecting the last one line string. Bits of a string are not available as properties. If `tf` is a cmdlet that's putting an array of objects on the pipeline, then it can certainly be done. Check out the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`.

Comment: @PaulHicks Well put; `tf` is indeed an external CLI (for TFS, the Team Foundation Server), not a cmdlet - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? You might be able to parse the output from `tf` with `ConvertFrom-String`, available in version 5.0

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no simple way to treat a string as an object with properties inferred from the contents of the string. You will have to mess about with `substring`, `indexof`, etc.

It is very likely that the TFS assemblies are suitable for calling directly from your powershell script. If you can figure out which method in those assemblies give you the same information as `tf labels /owner:LBLD_V3_R10*` then you can pipe the collection returned from that method to `Select-Object -Last 1` and then call `Get-Member` to figure out what else you can do.  But that's worthy of an entirely new question.